# How can I create a jcharArray inside of a JNI-method?

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

I want convert a `char` array in C to `jcharArray` for the JNI-interface to pass this array from C to Java.

I found a short tutorial which I am using currently: http://joshuaoutwater.info/blog/?p=10

In this tutorial `jcharArray resultBuffer1` is passed as a parameter from Java. The problem is that I don't know how big `resultBuffer1` has to be at the time the JNI-method is called. So I need to create this jcharArray with a specific size in my JNI-method.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it's:

```
jcharArray charArr = (*env)->NewCharArray(env, size);
```

Comment: how do you populate it with data once it is created?